# javafx variables DATA transfer between TWO controller (set and get data in different controller) - Updated

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am trying to  transfer  variable from one controller to another but i am not getting correct output:

**My codes:**

```
   public class CustomControl extends AnchorPane implements Initializable {
    String customId;

    public CustomControl() {
        //if you want to set a FXML
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/res/customControl.fxml"));
        //Defines this class as the controller
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        //this.getStylesheets().add("/res/style.css"); <- if you want to set a css
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }

    }
        public String getCustomId() {
            return customId;
        }
    public void setCustomId(String customId) {
        return this.customId = customId;
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
          //Initializes the controller
    }
}
```

To set CustomId variable at other controller

```
CustomControl c = new CustomControl();
c.setCustomId("StackOverflow");
```

To get CustomId variable from other controller

```
CustomControl c = new CustomControl();
c.getCustomId();
System.out.Println(c.getCustomId());
```

It gives me output

`null`

but required is

`StackOverflow`

And i know a same question is already asked [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)  So, don't mark it as duplicate

***because***
In my question There are two controller at firstcontroller.java

```
 CustomControl c = new CustomControl();
    c.setCustomId("StackOverflow");
```

now at secondcontroller.java

```
CustomControl c = new CustomControl();
c.getCustomId();
  System.out.Println(c.getCustomId());
```

as we are getting as setting data in different controller so it gives me the output

`null`

please please please help me.
Thank You.

Comment: i had already told in my question that i know about this answer but this doesn't fit in my question

Comment: it doesn't help to post the exact same question again and again - as @James_D already suggested: if you don't understand the answer you'll have to learn some basics first. Closing this again as duplicate. Note that you can edit the question and clarify why you think and how exactly your problem differs from the answered one. Also, you might consider adding a SSCCE (short, standalone, runnable) example demonstrating the problem (please see the faq on how-to-ask for details)

Comment: i need help in my codes.

Answer (score 1):

In secondcontroller.java, you are instantiating a **new** object, *c.*

```
CustomControl c = new CustomControl();
c.getCustomId();
  System.out.Println(c.getCustomId());
```

This **does not** refer to the object of the same name in *firstcontroller.java*. You will need to pass the object *c* instantiated in *firstcontroller.java* to *secondcontroller.java* if you wish to access it there.

Comment: my making c public static or some thing else

Comment: i am not getting my desired output please help me.